# how to convert hardcoded page template reference to class attribute in plone.app.z3cform to allow override by z3c.jbot

Tags: plone, z3c.form

The file `plone/app/z3cform/templates.py` contains the following references to the page template file `plone/app/z3cform/templates/widget.pt`

```
# The widget rendering templates need to be Zope 3 templates
class RenderWidget(ViewMixinForTemplates, BrowserView):
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/widget.pt')
class RenderSingleCheckboxWidget(ViewMixinForTemplates, BrowserView):
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/singlecheckbox.pt')
```

I am hoping that this explains why overrides to `plone/app/z3cform/templates/widget.pt` are not picked up by `z3c.jbot`, which depends on the page template being a class attribute.

If it does, I'm only too happy to try making and submitting the needed changes to allow `widget.pt` to be overriden via `z3c.jbot`, but I'm at a loss as to where to begin to look at what needs to be done to make these two filenames class attributes, especially in a Zopish/Plonish way.  So a few questions.  First, is this indeed the problem?  And, if so, how does one properly convert these hardcoded references to class attributes (of classes `RenderWidget` and `RenderSingleCheckboxWidget`?)

Comment: I think z3c.jbot should work with any .pt file: what jbot filename are you using?